# how to to first check whether the table exist or not before creating it in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, create-table

How to check whether a table already exists or not before executing a creation script?

for example in MySQL database, we can do

```
IF NOT EXISTS tableName ..then create table sql script to follow
```

how about in PostgreSQL?
Is there a way to check first if the table exists before creating it?
How do we do it?

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1 or Postgres 9.3? Bot are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses the following syntax:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    -- Column definitions...
)
```

Comment: how about when checking whether an index exist or not before creating it ?

Comment: @sasori there's a similar `create index if not exists` syntax, although it was only added in PostgreSQL 9.4